# I want to create boundaries of a zipcode using google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want to create boundaries of a zipcode using google map places api but unable to find the boundary coordinates.

I noticed when I search a zipcode on maps.google.com it shows a dotted boundary of that particular zipcode. How can I achieve this using google services?

Comment: That data is (still) not available via Google's API. You may be able to use styling to display it.

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks for the reply. How can I achieve this only by styling without making a shape/polygon for the borders of that zipcode?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with DDS ([Data-driven styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/overview)) if zipcode is available in the country/countries you are after (check [coverage](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/coverage#coverage-legend)).

Note this feature is still in Preview (Pre-GA) at this time.

Below is an example drawing the boundaries of a random postal code in Italy ([10123 Torino, Italy](https://www.google.com/maps/place/10123+Turin,+Metropolitan+City+of+Turin,+Italy/@45.0641079,7.6845715,16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47886d65d7b3baff:0x1c05e68093b7a470!8m2!3d45.0629159!4d7.6894974)).

To reproduce, you need to create a new map ID and map style in your Google Maps Platform console and select the appropriate feature layer(s). All information is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/start).

```js
let map;
let featureLayer;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 45.064335, lng: 7.688176 },
    zoom: 13,
    mapId: "8ec1ff859561face", // You need to create your own map ID
  });

  featureLayer = map.getFeatureLayer("POSTAL_CODE");

  // Define the styling options
  const featureStyleOptions = {
    strokeColor: "#00FF00",
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#519400',
    fillOpacity: 1,
  };

  // Apply the style to a single boundary.
  featureLayer.style = (options) => {
    if (options.feature.placeId == "ChIJ_7qz12VtiEcRcKS3k4DmBRw") {
      // Above Place ID is zipcode 10123 Torino, Italy
      return featureStyleOptions;
    }
  };
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=beta" defer></script>
```